# Redirect to reset password page if user has not logged in during the past 60 days in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, codeigniter

I have users table where I am storing the user logged in time in a timestamp column and the datatype is `int(11)`. I am trying to check which users have not logged in during the past 60 days and redirect them to the reset password page. Can any one help me how to do that?

Here is my controller:

```
public function login_user() {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean', 'required');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('login_view');
    } else {
        $data = array(
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'password' => $this->input->post('password')
        );
        $result = $this->Login_model->login($data);
        $sessionres = $this->Login_model->sessionStore($data);

        if ($result == 1) {
            $userData = $this->Login_model->getUserData($data);
            $sessionArray = array(
                'is_logged' => TRUE,
                'user_name' => $data['username'],
                'first_name' => $userData['firstname'],
                'last_name' => $userData['lastname'],
                'userlevel' => $userData['userlevel'],
                'organisation_id' => $userData['organisation_id'],
                'user_id' => $userData['id'],
                'lastip' => $userData['lastip']

            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($sessionArray);
            redirect('dashboard');
        } else if ($result == 2) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Password seems to be wrong!');
            $this->load->view('login_view', $data);
        } else if ($result == 4) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Username is not active!');
            $this->load->view('login_view', $data);
        }else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Username not found!');
            $this->load->view('login_view', $data);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: none of the code above relates to timestamps, or contains any code which would seem to relate to handling that case. What have you actually tried? I see no attempt here. What problem are you facing, exactly? What is puzzling you?

Comment: i haven't tried anything yet i ddin't get idea of how to do that i ahve posted my login code tahts it

Comment: can you please give me suggestion on what i have to do

Comment: well it seems obvious that you need to retrieve that field value from the database, read it, and check whether it's more than 60 days ago. If so then redirect them. None of that sounds very difficult, especially seeing as, looking at the code you've posted already, you seem to know how to do most of those tasks already (albeit using other fields). So again, what are you stuck with? We are not a free write-my-code service, we'll help you fix bugs with your attempt. We're volunteers, it's our free time and effort. We'll spend ours if we can see you've spent some of yours first.

Comment: On which  column you have the user's last logged in time? and why do you have an int data type for a timestamp?

Comment: timestamp column  i am storing

Comment: "timestamp column i am storing"...but in the question you said "timestamp column and the datatype is int(11)"...int is not timestamp. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html

Comment: yes i know that this code was written by someone and i am modifying in it ..i haven't create the tables

Comment: Well that's fine but it doesn't stop you being accurate about what is currently there. Don't contradict yourself like you just did, it confuses everyone else. Very hard to help without accurate information.

Comment: okay fine can i make timestamp comun datatype to timestamp?

Comment: if you want to. It depends whether you can convert what's there already into a timestamp, and whether you are able to alter the code which writes values into it in the first place. TBH though it doesn't matter too much as long as whatever's in the `int` column can be interpreted into a date reliably (perhaps it's storing a UNIX timestamp value for instance, PHP can read those very easily). It might be simpler not to change it if it's there already and populated with existing data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you have the user's last logged in timestamp, then you could check if it falls within the last two months, and if not, redirect the user to password reset page.

Let's say you have the user's last logged in time in `$userData['timestamp']`, then just before `redirect('dashboard');` you can add something like this:

```
$this->session->set_userdata($sessionArray);

if ($userData['timestamp'] > strtotime('-2 months')){
    redirect('dashboard');
    die();
}else{
    redirect('reset-password');
    die();
}
```

I assume that `'reset-password'` is the route to password reset page and `$userData['timestamp']` contains the user's last logged in time.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Great @user200!

Comment: hi i am storing timestamp datatype is int(11) willl it make problem?

Comment: because i have one user which timestamp date is todays date but still he cant able to login he is redirecting to reset password page

Comment: this condition is not working properly..don't know the exact reason

Comment: What do you mean by "not working properly" ? can you give an example?

Comment: yeah i am trying to login with one user whch timestamp value has today value when i try to login it takes me to reset password page

Comment: and at the same time i am trying to login with the user which has been created in 4 months back its redirecting to reset password page..showing this error too sometimes Message: Undefined variable: userData

Comment: @user200 I think there is a mistake. I think the redirect pages should be changed. and also, to avoid further redirections once the condition is met, you can use a die() function. Let me update my answer.

Comment: @user200 I changed the answer. Please check.

Comment: still its making same problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174857/discussion-between-user200-and-nimeshka-srimal).

Comment: @user200, please post your new code after adding the conditions so I can check.